# Install different variant of program depending on condition

Tags: windows-installer

I am building an MSI package that should install one of multiple versions of a specific executable, depending on Windows version (i.e. one that uses new functionality in Windows Vista, and one that does the work itself).

The name of the executable should be the same, whichever version is installed (otherwise this would be trivial, no?).

What is the correct way to achieve this using Windows Installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute best way to do this is to make the EXE file able to detect its own operating environment and choose a different method depending on what the OS provides so that there is only one binary to deal with.

There are many reasons for this:

- a separate binary is almost like a dual code base in the sense that it must go through a full, separate QA for each release and it is generally easier to debug and fix a single binary
- different binaries could lead to patching and upgrade problems and these are notoriously hard to debug and fix
- your installer won't pass windows installer validation if you use the same installation location for different files with the same name. This is generally not a problem unless you are aiming for certification from Microsoft for your installer
- MSI is clunky when it comes to deployment of different versions of the same file

If you must deploy two binaries I would create a new component with another copy of the EXE file and install it either with a different file name or with the same file name but in a different installation folder. You then condition the components with the files to be mutually exclusive for installation by using windows installer conditions. This would allow proper patching and upgrade.

Comment: Additionally, if a user upgrades from XP to Vista - now you have the "wrong" binary installed.

Comment: This would be fixable by a "repair" install. My point is that I'd rather avoid the complexity introduced by now having to late-bind DLLs so my binary can load without them on XP.

Comment: Hmm, sounds hairy. I would think there are compiler flags to handle building logic for this into the EXE for you, but I am not sure. Worth a C++ question? Seeing as this has to do with load behavior it might not be possible to put in the EXE, but Windows does have the "compatibility flag" for binaries (see in property tab for the file in windows explorer, compatibility tab). Could you somehow enable this flag to force a load behavior or enable Windows compatibility feature to help you avoid taking on the headache yourself?

Comment: Simon, also remember to set the transient attribute for components with conditions in this case. Otherwise repair might not put the right file back.

Comment: This was the exact idea -- have transient components that are mutually exclusive and tailored to the Windows version installed. For COM components that has worked well, since neither the OS nor the user care too much how the DLL is named (and as I stole the idea from the SDK MSI, I think this is somewhat correct); this only becomes difficult with executables that should be called from the command line.

Comment: Compatibility Mode would only be useful to run the XP application on Vista -- which works fine, but Vista's Function Discovery Service is getting slightly confused if I do things by hand rather than query Function Discovery.